# Implementing custom swipe functionality in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I am attempting to recreate an effect seen in many apps, you have a table view with cells, swipe on a cell and the view is replaced by another view containing additional buttons.

I attempted to do this as follows:

```
    // Hacky hacky
    RCTReceiptCell *selectedCell = (RCTReceiptCell *)[sender view];

    RCTReceiptOptionsCell *optionsCell = [[RCTReceiptOptionsCell alloc] init];

    if (optionsCell) {
        NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *class = NSStringFromClass([RCTReceiptOptionsCell class]);
        NSArray *cellComponents = [mainBundle loadNibNamed:class
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil];
        optionsCell = [cellComponents objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // Make sure subview gets inserted on top.
    NSArray *subviews = [[selectedCell contentView] subviews];
//  NSUInteger index = [subviews indexOfObject:[subviews lastObject]];
    UIView *selectedCellContentView = selectedCell.contentView;
    [selectedCell insertSubview:optionsCell aboveSubview:selectedCell.contentView];
    NSLog(@"subviews: %@",selectedCellContentView.subviews);
```

The challenge I faced was getting the view to stay on the cell. What happens instead is the view briefly appears and then disappears. How can I get it to stay and then how can I get it to disappear once another touch event takes place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial. Is that what you were looking for?

http://idevrecipes.com/2011/04/14/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-side-swiping-on-a-table/